# How do you add translation for extensions in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, extensions, localisation, magento-2.0.7

I installed IWC's One Page Checkout (OPC) extension and even though it works properly, we just can't translate it into Spanish.

We have a language pack `es_MX.csv` (Spanish/Mexico) with translations for the whole site. Everything pulls the right string except for the OPC.

Should I create an additional CSV file? Where?

Comment: For language translation you can use Magento 2 Language Translator extension. This extension helps you to get over the hassles of converting content into excel sheet and importing it back to your website. https://www.appjetty.com/magento2-language-translator.htm

Answer (score 14):

I assume you mean IWD OPC? If not you can ignore this answer.

The checkout extension ships without translations. It should be fairly easy to generate those.

First, you need to create i18n directory inside the module so the structure is

```
<mage_dir>/app/code/Vendor/Opc/i18n
```

Then generate the dictionary with magento shell tool; from :

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o app/code/Vendor/Opc/i18n/en_US.csv app/code/Vendor/Opc/
```

Use the proper folder instead of 'Vendor'. Now you have a full dictionary for the module.

Finally, duplicate the `en_US.csv` file in the i18n directory and rename it to `es_MX.csv`.

Translate the content, clear caches and the phrases will be translated.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but not working. we installed same module (IWD/Opc)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create i18n directory inside the module so the structure will be like below.
[image]

Now create .csv file for the locale in which you want to translate like fr_FR.csv
So your final translation file path is

[image]